# Marrying an older women

Tags: husband-wife

I recently met a practicing women. She wishes to get married and we really like each other. However she is 34 and I am 23 and she also has two children.

I do like her but I’m worried about what my family will think. What does Islam say about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Islam doesn't concern itself with things such as age difference , I believe that was mentioned several times with respect to nikah .
As for the fact that she is an older woman , as long as the marriage has all the requirements of an Islamic marriage and all the proceedings are done correctly , then I don't see why it should be treated any differently than a regular marriage .

**Side note** : Prophet Mohammed (PBUH) married Khadija (RA) , his first wife and mother of most of his children at the age of 25 , whilst she was 40 .
**Thus we can see that it is completely acceptable in Islam** .

Answer (score 2):

A woman can marry a man younger or older than her. There is no drawback to it. Our Prophet (pbuh) married Hazrat Khadijah, who was older than him.
It is very important for the peace of the home to be established and the training and education of the children to be born that the man choose the girl to marry carefully and the parents of the girl choose the son-in-law carefully. Our Prophet, who advised us to be careful in choosing the son-in-law and daughter-in-law, wanted us to be cautious by saying, "People are like mines in terms of good deeds and bad deeds."

Hazrat Umar tells the following three things to his son who asks him about the rights of a child regarding his father: 'Choose a mother with high ethics and good manners, give him/her a nice name, and teach him/her the Quran."

So, I think it is clear that there is no objection in islam about this issue.